# Lightning Datatable Column headers are overflowing when browser window size changing by the user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, style

I have an Aura component showing a Lightning Datatable with some columns.
I'm using Word wrap to fit/read the table contents within the table.

But the issue is whenever user is increasing the browser size, only the column headers are oveflowing as shown below.

[image]

How to fix this ? How to make the column headers to stay within the column bar ?
I have tried almost all the alternatives to fix the position of column headers with no luck.

I'm currently using below css for the word wrap.

```
/*Word wrap the cell content and column header*/
.THIS .slds-truncate {
    text-overflow: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not meant to use wrapping on the headers. That's what `slds-truncate` does; it cuts the label off short when it's too long. You can add `word-break: keep-all` to try and prevent the unnecessary breaks, but the labels may overflow the cell header into the next cell.